# Dynamic Callback on useState React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback

I want to run a function ONLY some of the time I update a state values using setter function of useState hook in react, how would I do it?

In my code flow, I update the state value in multiple places, but need to run callbacks only on few of them, because of this I can't use the useEffect way which is widely prescribed.

Comment: What does this function do? Is there something about it that means you can't call it manually after setting state without waiting for the rerender? (ie, `setState('new value'); doOtherStuff();`)

Comment: Yes, I am setting focus to an input using ref in callback, and I am using this useState to remove mui popover (setAnchorEl(null)), if I just call this callback after setState, input loses focus as setState is asynchronous